# "Matrices are not aligned" error in toy example of ols using gneiss

Tags: python, linear-regression, statsmodels, coda

I am attempting to build a trivial example of a linear regression for compositional data. I'm using the following code:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np
from skbio import TreeNode
from gneiss.regression import ols
from IPython.display import display

#define table of compositions
yTrain = DataFrame({'y1': [0.8, 0.3, 0.5], 'y2': [0.2, 0.7, 0.5]})

#define predictors for compositions
xTrain = DataFrame({'x1': [1,3,2]})

#Once these variables are defined, a regression can be performed. These proportions will be converted to balances according to the tree specified. And the regression formula is specified to run temp and ph against the proportions in a single model.
model = ols('x1', yTrain, xTrain)
model.fit()
xTest = DataFrame({'x1': [1,3]})
yTest = model.predict(xTest)
display(yTest)
```

I'm getting the error `matrices are not aligned`. Any idea on how to get this running?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have mixed up your `x` and `y` matrices between the training and test stages. Your `xTest` should perhaps be identical in structure to `yTrain`. In your code `xTest` looks like `xTrain` which seems to correspond to labels.

The general convention in ML is to use `x` for inputs and `y` for outputs. In your case, you have used `y` for inputs and `x` for labels during training, and the other way around during testing.

For instance, try setting xTest to the following:

```
xTest = DataFrame({'y1': [0.1, 0.4, 0.6], 'y2': [0.4, 0.2, 0.8]})
```

That should get rid of the error. You would ideally do something along the lines of the following:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np
from skbio import TreeNode
from gneiss.regression import ols
from IPython.display import display

#define table of compositions
xTrain = DataFrame({'x1': [0.8, 0.3, 0.5], 'x2': [0.2, 0.7, 0.5]})

#define predictors for compositions
yTrain = DataFrame({'y1': [1,3,2]})

model = ols('y1', xTrain, yTrain)
model.fit()
xTest = DataFrame({'x1': [0.1, 0.4, 0.6], 'x2': [0.4, 0.2, 0.8]})
yTest = model.predict(xTest)
display(yTest)
```

Comment: Thanks for looking a this, but the code you posted results in the same error.

Comment: I found where the error pops up within the `gneiss` library, but it doesn't make sense to me without knowing the context of the problem you're solving. Could you perhaps briefly go over what exactly it is you're trying to do with the above data nd model? It appears that my assumption that you're looking to predict the values of `yTest` given the values of input features `xTest` may not have been correct.